# "IP_TRANSPARENT" was not declared in this scope

Tags: c, sockets, setsockopt

I try to use IP_TRANSPARENT socket option. But I got "IP_TRANSPARENT" was not declared in this scope. If I directly use its code (19) in the code, I got binding error as : "invalid argument". Should I recompile my kernel to support this option? If it is the case, I use kernel 2.6.32. I couldn't find any option in the kernel parameter interface.

Any thoughts?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Using the value 19 if it is not defined by your C library's header files is ok, it's not what's causing it to return -EINVAL.

But there are a few kernel options that need to be enabled for this to work. To quote the documentation (in the kernel source, Documentation/networking/tproxy.txt):

> This feature adds Linux 2.2-like transparent proxy support to current
>   kernels. To use it, enable NETFILTER_TPROXY, the socket match and the
>   TPROXY target in your kernel config. You will need policy routing too,
>   so be sure to enable that as well.

You can find more information in that document, or read it online here: http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/networking/tproxy.txt